# npm sql pool from postgre to mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, npm

I'm having this code:

```
    console.log("-------------- Connecting to the database...");
    const client = await pool.connect();
    console.log("-------------- Connection process done.");
    console.log("-------------- Now Querying.");  
    var sql = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '${email}'`;
    console.log("-------------- Query done.");
    let query = await client.query(sql);
    client.release();
    pool.release();
    if(query.rows[0]){return "Email already exists. Please login."}
    return 0;
```

I want to do that with:

```
    pool.getConnection
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your using the npm package `mysql` within the readme you can find doumentation regarding the pool topic.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
const pool  = mysql.createPool(...);

const email = "test@example.com" // Users email address variable.

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  if (err) throw err; // not connected!

  // Use the connection
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], function (error, results, fields) {
    // When done with the connection, release it.
    connection.release();

    // Handle error after the release.
    if (error) throw error;

    // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.

    if(!results.length) {
     // No results found.
    }else {
     // Results found.
    }
  });
});
```

I haven't tested this code, if you do have trouble with it check out the documentation.